# onclick event on dynamic element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, onclick, event-listener

i am trying to attach an event listener to a static element to allow onclicks on my dynamic images to work. I cannot for the life of me seem to achieve this. I have repeatedly searched and copied the answers in other posts but to no avail.

I'm not sure what im doing wrong, whether it be a bug in my code or that im just missing something all together.

Any help would be appreciated, below is my code:

```
$(document).on('click','.newsfeed-bump',function(bump_hype_product){
jQuery('#product-message-confirmation-wrap').hide();
jQuery('.popup-waiting-wrap').show();
jQuery('#modal_product_message_confirmation h4.modal-title').html('');

jQuery.ajax({
    url : the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'bump_hype_product',
        type : type_text,
        post_id : post_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {

        jQuery('.popup-waiting-wrap').hide();
        jQuery('#product-message-confirmation-wrap').show();
        jQuery('#product-message-confirmation-wrap').html(response);

        jQuery('#modal_product_message_confirmation').modal('show');
    }
});
                        });
```

Im getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: type_text is not defined"

Comment: So you have an element with `id="document"` ?

Comment: `$('#document')` means you are looking for an element with ID `document`, really?! I guess `$(document)` would work better...

Comment: Can you show a JSfiddle example?

Comment: Do you have any element with id="document"?

Comment: no i dont, ive tried multiple different elements, e.g 'body', thats just the last one i attempted as i reading some other answers regarding similar problems. the images parent div is also dynamically added so im not sure if i can use that

Comment: Try $(document.body)

Comment: @SunnySoni Better would be to use `$(document)` because at least it can be set **before** the `body` is available, meaning set in `head` section

Comment: It should just be `$(document).on("click", ".classOfWhatYouWantToListenToClickOn", function(){});`

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah right

Comment: Okay so ive corrected my $(document) error but it still doesnt seem to work, i looked in the console on inspect element and its saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: type_text is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
$('#document').on('click','.newsfeed-bump',bump_hype_product,function(){
   // your logic
}
```

Comment: Hopefully '#document' is a id for an element, but if you are referring to the javascript document object, use this instead: $(document)

Comment: @Ryan the third argument is the data you are passing to the event handler. for some reason you cant pass the data directly inside the event handler parenthesis. Hope this helps

Comment: @Samir, please explain

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$("body").delegate(".newsfeed-bump", "click", function(){
    //your code
});
```

or

```
$("body").on("click", ".newsfeed-bump" function(){
    //your code
});
```